# Missing permission when trying to remove a role with string variable as the argument in name parameter

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a function which removes a role from an user for a certain time. It works fine with predefined role names like:

```
role_to_remove = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="placeholder")
```

But it doesn't work when I'm setting roles using commands, which save the user input in string variable.
Here is the function which removes roles:

```
role1_name = ''
role2_name = ''
roleDefault_name = ''

@client.command()
@commands.has_role('VIP')
async def deleterole(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    role_to_remove = roleDefault_name
    for role in member.roles:
        if role == role2_name:
            role_to_remove = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role2_name)
        elif role == role1_name:
            role_to_remove = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role1_name)
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"None of the roles specified in config are assigned to {member}")
            role_to_remove = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=roleDefault_name)
    await member.remove_roles(role_to_remove)
    await asyncio.sleep(60.0)
    await member.add_roles(role_to_remove)
```

These are functions which are used to set role names by user:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def set_role1_name(ctx, role1):
    global role1_name
    role1_name = role1

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def set_role2_name(ctx, role2):
    global role2_name
    role2_name = role2

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def set_role_default(ctx, roledefault):
    global roleDefault_name
    roleDefault_name = roledefault
```

When I use the deleterole command, I get the following error (despite the fact that the bot has administrator permissions):

> discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

Comment: Are you using a custom role for your bot and are you sure it has administrator permissions. If I click off the Administer permissions of my role it gives the Forbidden message, giving back the permissions gets rid of the error. Once fixed you'll be able to debug the logic errors in the `deleterole` function.

Comment: I'm sure that I have correct role names and my bot has administrator permissions. I tried it on multiple servers and it gives me the same error every time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are actually getting the correct role to remove and not `None`?

`discord.utils.get` returns None when it does not find a role with the specified name and trying to remove a role that does not exist might trigger a 403 Forbidden.

Comment: I'm sure that the role names I type in set_role1_name, set_role2_name and set_role_default are correct, so discord.utils.get should return something but I can't print it because I keep getting the error.

Comment: Wait, on what line does the error happen? Because in your post you said it happens when you try to remove the role from a user, but now you are saying you can't even print it?

Comment: I managed to print role_to_remove ant it is: vip (this is what I set using set_role_default command earlier). 
I modified the code:
`if role_to_remove is not None:
          await member.remove_roles(role_to_remove)
else:
           await ctx.send("Role_to_remove is None")`
I still get the error when setting roles using set_role commands, but when I don't set anything at all and just run deleterole command I get "Role_to_remove is None" message.